# Help to create my own personnal Cls

Tags: mwcls

Heller
Can someone help me to create a personal .cls file, I am tired of handling dozens of lines of code in the preamble each time.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Rather than create your own cls class file, it would be simpler to create your own sty file `\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}...\endinput` and then `\usepackage{mystyle}` when you want to use it, or even simpler, to just place the oft used code in a separate file (say `mycmds.tex`) and issue `\input mycmds.tex` in the preamble, when you want to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your help; i used the last proposition !!